# Magento 2 EE , Getting error while reorder from admin

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento EE 2.2.2 version and am facing issue while reorder from admin. I have upgraded from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2 version then only getting issue.

Getting error like " Product "1005961_38_B" not found. This product is no longer available."

Issue only for configurable products, working for simple products.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, I have the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue. I did debug and found that the catalog_product_super_link (parent_id) table has foreign constraint with catalog_product_entity(row_id)
This issue is occurring if data in the row_id an entity_id are differ

**Example**
*catlog_product_entity*

It should be like as below

row_id    entity_id

1                 1

2                      2

3                      3

But entries are like below (both column values are not same

row_id   entity_id

1                      1

3                      2

5                      3

For temporary fix, i changed the reference key from row_id to entity_id of catalog_product_entity(as the same structure in community edition)